# how to post tweet from asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, twitter, webforms

I am trying to following tutorial to post tweet to twitter but it is not working for it

http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/ASP-Twitter-Posting.aspx

Is their another way or if some can point me to a good tutorial which show how toppost tweet using asp.net C# web application

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = "YOUR_USER_NAME";
    string password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
    string tweet = TextBox1.Text;

    try 
    {
        string user = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));  
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + tweet);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml");

        request.Method="POST";
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + user);
        request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   

        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        /* DO NOTHING */
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain _" it is not working"_ - Do you get an exception? And I guess even if you *did* get an exception you wouldn't know since you have ***DO NOTHING*** in your exception handler

Comment: @Blachshma, It doesn't post to twitter not it generate any error . Code executes without any error without post anything on twotter

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, have you checked for any exceptions on your `catch` block ?

Comment: @DON, I checked that it doesn't generate any exception. code exceute with out any exception..

Comment: Have you replaced `username` and `password` with the one you registered?

Comment: Yes i place the correct username & password....

Answer (score 2):

That's an old tutorial as Twitter deprecated basic authentication years ago. These days, you must use OAuth, which Twitter describes in their [OAuth Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth). If you prefer not to write your own OAuth code, you can do a search for 3rd party libraries, DotNetOpenAuth comes to mind, or use a library that does this for you, which you can find on the [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) page.

Disclaimer: I wrote one of the libraries on the Twitter Libraries page, named [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/).

Note: You'll want to target the Twitter API v1.1 as the Twitter API v1.0 is now deprecated and will be turned off next month.

I also noticed that you seem to be having difficulty figuring out what the problem is. My best guess is that you're receiving an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response from Twitter. If you called GetResponse() on the request, this 401 response would cause an exception to be raised, but that isn't happening in your code because you're just pushing the request. You should call GetResponse to ensure you know how Twitter reacted to your code. Then you can hit a break point on your catch block or log the response to see what the problem is - sometimes you'll have to examine the fields of the exception to obtain more information. Another great debugging tool is Fiddler, which lets you examine the response from Twitter. FireBug and IE F12 tools are other options (there are probably more), but the goal is to see what Twitter is telling you.

Comment: I am using Twitterizer2lite.dll will it also not works it seems to be using OAuth but i am not sure i have to check the documentaion

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Sounds like a different subject from your question here. Maybe you can post a new question with the new code you're trying to use and someone who knows that library might be able to help. I hope my answer helped you with your original question.